# Programatically getting the model types for a bunch of views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm looking to get the interfaces required for a bunch of views we have scattered across a number of projects. Is there a good way to retrieve the model/interface required for a given razor template/view? They all begin with something like:

```
@inherits Our.Custom.TypeOfView<IModel>
```

Where `TypeOfView` is a class that inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`.

I could potentially do some string searching through all the files, but it feels like there is probably a better way to directly get the information I'm interested in. Maybe there isn't? I don't know, that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Use reflection on the assembly they are in?

Answer (score 1):

How about the Model Metadata?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Okay, this is probably going to be part of the solution

Comment: Ideally I there should be a decent way to fetch the model off of the view file, not sure what that might look like though